# Velocity Templates HTML: How to use URLs with "&" in template?

Tags: url, escaping, velocity

I want to use a barcode generator in velocity html template to place a barcode image. Unfortunately I need to send some parameters with "&" and the XMl Renderer alsways interprets this as an entity.

Example template code:

```
<img src="http://server/barcode-servlet?data=${barcodeId}&type=Int2of5&height=50"/>
```

The error I get is:

```
XMLParser: Entity Reference must end on ;
```

How can I escape / use "&" parameters in URLs in Velocity? It doesn't help to put all of it in variables and concat them...

Comment: I think you need escape them in the way HTML/XML understands it. E.g: you can escape & as `&amp;`...

Comment: No, then it's interpreted as a part of the "data=" part (as a String), I already tried that.

Comment: Can you show me how it gets rendered? The velocity template...

Comment: I can't show the details at the moment (wrong place now). It's rendered in Java using a "VelocityHelper" with an XHTML or XML renderer as I remember. I guess that's why it's having problems with `&`.